# Metamask app detect my dapp as phishing

Tags: metamask, dapps, phishing

I create a dapp and made a website. The first few days the metamask app (Android) worked fine with it, but then it identified my site as phishing and shows a red warning page. How can I fix this problem?
my dapp: https://smartdot-project.web.app/
Description of my dapp: https://smartdot.xyz/
github my app: https://github.com/chelbukhov/SmartDotApp

Comment: You should contact Metamask customer support. Being honest the web doesn't look professional.

Comment: you're right, this is just a prototype app for feature testing. there is no design. And I contacted support - they advised me to post the question here. :)))